# Order records based on calculation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm currently finding the players with the most goals like such:

```
Player.joins(:player_stats).group('players.id').order('SUM(player_stats.goals) DESC')
```

However now I want to order by goals per game, which is the sum of all their goals (player_stats.goals) divided by the number of games they have played (players_stats.length). Is it possible to do arithmetic like this when sorting using order()?

NOTE: I'm working on a mySQL database.

Comment: `Player.joins(:player_stats).group('players.id').order('(SUM(player_stats.goals) / COUNT(player_stats.player_id)) DESC')`?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along these lines would do:

```
Player.joins(:player_stats)
      .group('players.id')
      .order('(SUM(p‌​layer_stats.goals) / COUNT(player_stats.player_id)) DESC')
```